# Найти формулу для подсчёта всех вариантов троек значений валютных пар

Tags: java, алгоритм, формулы

В первой строке вводятся три целых числа - курс валют. Во второй строке вводится три целых чилса - кол-во первой второй и третьей валюты соответственно.Допутим у нас есть три валюты A, B и С и каждая из них имеет свою ценность *a b* и *c* соответственно: если мы хотим обменять валюту A на валюту B, то мы должны отдать ровно *a* единиц валюты А и получить взамен ровно *b* единиц валюты B. Требуется подсчитать количество разных троек значений, которые мы можем получить путем обменных операций. Желательно на языке java, но можно и просто формулу вывести.

```
Пример 1:

 1 1 1
 1 0 2

Вывод: 10

Пример 2:
 1 2 3
 3 4 5

Вывод: 28
```

Comment: Как получаются эти количества? из вопроса я ничего не понял...

Comment: Все возможные комбинации троек значений путем обменных операций одну валюту на другую.

Comment: Думается, нужно смотреть в сторону рекурсии.

Comment: задача о числе способов разложить  K шаров по 3-м карнизам. `K=A//a + B//b + C//c` где `//`  - целочисленное деление.

Comment: Сдаюсь, но я реально не понимаю смысл задачи... Математическая формулировка у нее есть?

Comment: @Harry Вы, может, логику пытаетесь включить, но тут своя атмосфера... То, что называется ценностью - на самом деле "дешевизна ", измеряется в обратных граммах условного золота: `a` тугриков, `b` дукатов, `c` фартингов за один грамм золота. И обмены только через этот один грамм выполняются.

Comment: @MBo Я просто пытаюсь понять, что надо получить, хотя бы как получить эти числа в примерах. Ладно, раз есть ответ - проехали, не буду и пытаться разобраться...

Comment: @Harry Для второго примера за один шаг можно получить расклады `3-1 4+2 5, 3+1 4-2 5, 3-1 4 5+3, 3+1 4 5-3, 3 4-2 5+3, 3 4+2 5-3`, за два шага ещё какие-то и т.д., пока все возможные триплеты не будут перечислены

Comment: @MBo Наверное, тупой я сегодня с утра :( Ладно, замечу только, что если есть какие-то состояния (расклады, как вы выразились) и какие-то шаги, переводящие одно состояние в другое, то это связный граф, так что можно поиграть в поиск в ширину, например.

Comment: @Harry  Вообще это щадящий вариант;), в дубликатном вопросе началось с такого: `Не могу сообразить, как реализовать алгоритм генерации 3 чисел, у каждого числа своя стоимость(количество использований). Нужно получить количество возможных комбинаций`

Comment: @MBo Это уже в "Что, где, когда"...

Comment: `(K+1)*(K+2)//2` где K  уже посчитал Chorkov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если готовая формула не приходит на ум, но можно разложить задачу на элементарные подзадачи – время использовать рекурсию :)

Набросал код на C#, показать идею:

```
static List<(int, int, int)> results;

static void MakeExchange(int[] currencyValues, int[] currencyAmounts)
{
    // инициализация рекурсии
    results = new();
    results.Add((currencyAmounts[0], currencyAmounts[1], currencyAmounts[2]));
    MakeExchangeStep(currencyValues, currencyAmounts, currencyAmounts);
}

static void MakeExchangeStep(int[] currencyValues, int[] currencyAmounts, int[] currentAmounts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) continue;
            if (currentAmounts[i] < currencyValues[i]) continue; // если валюты I (которую "отдаем") "мало" - то пропускаем ее

            var newAmounts = new int[3]; // создаем копию массива остатков валют, т.к. массивы передаются по ссылке
            currentAmounts.CopyTo(newAmounts, 0);
            newAmounts[i] -= currencyValues[i]; // отдаем i единиц валюты I
            newAmounts[j] += currencyValues[j]; // получаем "взамен" j единиц валюты J

            // формируем комбинацию остатков и смотрим, получали ли мы ее ранее
            var result = (newAmounts[0], newAmounts[1], newAmounts[2]);
            if (!results.Contains(result))
            {
                // если нет - добавляем комбинацию в список результатов и запускаем по ней шаг рекурсии
                results.Add(result);
                MakeExchangeStep(currencyValues, currencyAmounts, newAmounts);
            }
        }
}
```

Идея в том, что на вход шага рекурсии мы получаем комбинацию остатков валют и пытаемся совершать всевозможные обмены каждой валюты на каждую по "одной" единице с соблюдением ограничений (имеется в виду минимальное количество валюты исходя из ее ценности). Если после очередного обмена мы получили новую комбинацию - запускаем по ней рекурсию. Явного выхода из рекурсии нет, т.к. она закончится естественным образом найдя все возможные комбинации остатков валют и не запустит более сама себя. Можно даже формально довольно несложно доказать останов и полноту рекурсии.

Небольшая ремарка: для упрощения кода я использовал структуру [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-6.0)  (синтаксис `(newAmounts[0], newAmounts[1], newAmounts[2])`), которая сама умеет сравнивать себя по значениям своих полей. В целом, здесь будет лучше написать, например, обертку на массивом, оставив индексацию и реализовав `Equals()` так, чтобы он сравнивал массивы поэлементно (хотя в Java вроде именно это делает `Arrays.equals()` - поправьте, если не прав). Тогда получим универсальное решение для любой длины входных данных.

Тест:

```
MakeExchange(new[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new[] { 1, 0, 2 });
Console.WriteLine(results.Count); // 10

MakeExchange(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 3, 4, 5 });
Console.WriteLine(results.Count); // 28
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае нам нужно решить уравнение: a*x + b*y + c*z = sum, где sum = a*x + b*y + c*z (из исходных данных), a,b,c - константы (курс валют). По сути нужен тройной цикл для перебора всех подходящих x,y,z - количество валюты (наши ответы).
Однако для второго примера:
1 2 3
3 4 5
Ответ будет 65, что вроде как неверно, но может они опечатались, потому что логика сходится.

Comment: у вас суть значений a b c  отличается от того, что этими буквами в задаче обозначено. см. комментарий chorkov