# Логи решения задачи про валюту

Tags: python

Здравствуй, дали тестовое задание:

Вот его описание (это не мой пост):
[Текст задачки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476164/%D0%92-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Подскажите пожалуйста логику?
Не могу понять, что хочет автор.

Пример: Ввод: 1 1 1 1 0 2 Вывод: 10 ------- Ввод: 1 2 3 3 5 4 Вывод: 28

Что такое 10, 28?

Comment: А вам зачем? :)

Comment: @MaxS, пробую решить с помощью Python

Comment: Вчера был аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1477300/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80/1477332#1477332

Comment: @MaxS, спасибо. Можете рассказать на пальцах откуда берется 10? Без кода простым языком.

Comment: Интересно, где такие тестовые дают в таком количестве? :)

Comment: У нас есть 1 единица 1-й валюты, 0 единиц второй, 2 единицы третьей. Даны обменные курсы (в данном примере 1-1-1). Можем менять валюты друг на друга как хотим. И получаем разные остатки валют на руках. Вот, просят посчитать количество разных таких комбинаций остатков валют. В данном примере это будет комбинация (0, 1, 2) со всеми перестановками (3! = 6 комбинаций), плюс (0, 0, 3) со всеми перестановками (3 комбинации), плюс комбинация (1, 1, 1). Итого 10. Со вторым примером посложнее, но принцип, думаю, уже понятен.

Comment: @MaxS, когда на стажировку в тинькофф регистрируешься, одна из 6 задач.

Comment: Видимо, много кандидатов, раз минимум уже третий вопрос здесь за последние 5 дней :)

Comment: Видимо. Я ее уже точно не прошел, вот и спрашиваю для себя. Спасибо за пояснение буду разбираться)